# Sending strings over UDP socket

Tags: android, string, sockets, udp, client

I am trying to make my test application send strings through a UDP socket. It keeps on throwing `AndroidRuntime` error on line `soc.send(pac);`. I already have required permissions set in the `android_manifest` file.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.DatagramPacket;
    import java.net.DatagramSocket;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     private EditText editText1;

    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String text= editText1.toString();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                udpmsg(text);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}

    public void udpmsg(String text) throws java.io.IOException 
    {
        InetAddress to = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.105");
        int port=55505;
        DatagramSocket soc = new DatagramSocket();
        byte[] data = text.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket pac = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, to, port);
        soc.send(pac);

        }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please use `AsyncTask` to send UDP packet... network operation should not be done in the UI thread...

Comment: @ lxx It shows androidruntime error on logcat and the application on the phone forcecloses

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar how do i do that im totally new to developing in android a little help would be much appreciated

Comment: check out this tutorial from android training http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html ... also please post the logcat logs...

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the *send* method of DatagramSocket can also throw *java.lang.SecurityException* which is a runtime exception and you're not catching it anywhere in your code.

As a quick check, replace *catch (IOException e) {* with *catch (Exception e) {* and tell us what is displayed in the log after this modification.

Comment: i told you to copy the error message so that we can understand what it means